# Problemas ao pegar no id do insert anterior

Tags: php, mysql

Código para inserir:

```
$codigoutente = $_POST['codigoutente']; 
$codvalencia = $_POST['codvalencia']; 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'];
$Contato = $_POST['Contato']; 

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Responsavel"]);$i++) { 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'][$i];

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
}
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;


for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Contato"]);$i++) { 
$Contato = $_POST['Contato'][$i];

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
}
```

O problema é a variável `$last_id`. Quando insiro dois novos responsáveis, no primeiro `insert` vai inserir duas linhas com dois `ids` diferentes, exemplo:

- id = 10  IdResponsável = Alberto IdUtente = 10115
- id = 11  IdResponsável = Armindo IdUtente = 10118

Depois ao fazer o segundo `insert` o id que pega da tabela anterior é sempre no último para os dois registos e não pode, tem que pegar no primeiro `insert` o `id = 10` e no segundo o `id = 11`.

Comment: `$_POST["Contato"]` e `$_POST["Responsavel"]`são arrays que está recebendo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que a variável `$last_id` esta fora do laço de repetição, existem 2 maneiras de resolver, você pode colocar o segundo **INSERT** dentro do primeiro laço  de repetição ou pode criar um vetor de `$last_id` para percorrer novamente quando for inseri o segundo **INSERT** (que foi o que fiz no código abaixo).

```
$codigoutente = $_POST['codigoutente']; 
$codvalencia = $_POST['codvalencia']; 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'];
$Contato = $_POST['Contato']; 

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Responsavel"]);$i++) { 
$Responsavel = $_POST['Responsavel'][$i];

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Responsaveis (`Responsavel`,`IdUtente`) VALUES ('$Responsavel','$codigoutente')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
$last_id_array[] = $conn->insert_id;
}


for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Contato"]);$i++) { 
$Contato = $_POST['Contato'][$i];
$last_id = $last_id_array[$i];
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ContatoRes (`IdUtente`,`IdResponsavel`,`Contato`) VALUES ('$codigoutente','$last_id','351$Contato')");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
}
```